# Trouble getting flash notice to display in page view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

So I'm having a weird problem with my Rails app not *displaying* a flash message. Before I start, I do have this code in my application.html.slim:

```
    - flash.each do |type, message|
      .flash
        = message
    = yield
```

which seems to work, because I have flash notices set up in other controllers, and they *do* display correctly. But there is one flash that isn't working.

The controller containing the offending -- specifically, "redirect_to @assignment, notice: "Assignment successfully created!":

```
class AssignmentsController < ActionController::Base

def new
  @assignment = Assignment.new
end

def create
  @assignment = Assignment.new(assignment_params)
  if @assignment.save
    redirect_to @assignment, notice: "Assignment successfully created!"
  else
    flash[:error] = "Error adding assignment. Please try again."
    render :edit
  end
end

private

def assignment_params
  params.require(:assignment).permit(:description)
end
```

app/assignments/show.html.slim is simply:

```
h3 Your assignments.
```

The page output is simply - without any notice -

```
Your assignments.
```

I inserted ( = debug flash ) to test if the notice was actually getting there, because it was driving me crazy, and it seems it is indeed getting there:

```
--- !ruby/object:ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash
discard: !ruby/object:Set
    hash:
      notice: true
flashes:
    notice: Assignment successfully created!
now: 

Your assignments.
```

I also wrote a couple of rspec tests. One is a controller test; it signs in a user, does

```
post :create, assignment: { description: blahblah }
```

and tests for the notice:

```
expect( flash[:notice] ).to eql 'Assignment successfully created!'
```

This test passes just fine, but a feature test using capybara just doesn't see the notice, just like I can't see the notice when trying it out manually.

So I've tried out a couple other things to troubleshoot, like seeing if putting

```
= flash.notice
```

directly into the show.html.slim would force the notice to display (it did!) and also tried putting it into the application.html.slim instead to see if that would work (it didn't work any better than what I already had there).

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

*Was going to write as a comment, but too long*

The way I see it, there are two ways you could have an issue here:

> 1. Your `flash` data won't be getting through to your controller
> 2. `Turbolinks` *may* be preventing it from showing

---

**Flash**

Your flash problem is certainly a perplexing one.

The two issues I can see with it are that you're calling it from your layout directly (IE not in the "yield"), or you're not referencing the correct data with the `- flash` call.

I would suggest that to test this out, you put the `- flash` loop into your actual view `#app/views/assignments/show.html.erb`, to test whether it will load each time you hit that page, like so:

```
#app/controllers/assignments_controller.rb
class AssignmentsController < ApplicationController
   def create
     @assignment = Assignment.new(assignment_params)
     if @assignment.save
       flash[:notice] = "Assignment successfully created!"
       redirect_to @assignment
     else
       flash[:error] = "Error adding assignment. Please try again."
       render :edit
     end
   end
end

#app/views/assignments/show.html.slim
- flash.each do |type, message|
      .flash
        = message
```

---

**Turbolinks**

This leads on from having your `- flash` loop in your layout, rather than view.

Although there's absolutely nothing wrong with what you've done, perhaps (and this is guesswork), your layout will not update because Turbolinks is preventing it from doing so. As unlikely as this is, you *may* wish to test disabling turbolinks for the link you're loading.

Quite interesting - I just looked up about this, and found [this reference](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#initialization):

> POST :create => resource successfully created => redirect to GET :show
>   Turbolinks ENABLED

This confirms that Turbolinks *will* be enabled for your call, and will therefore mean that your *layout* will be subject to its work. To disable Turbolinks for this request, I would recommend doing the following:

```
#app/views/assignments/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @assignment, html: { data-no-turbolink: true } do |f| %>
...
```

Although I'm not sure of the syntax, it should prevent Turbolinks from firing for that particular element, which will basically tell Rails to load up the `layout` from scratch (with Turbolinks, it will only refresh the `<body>` tag I believe).

Another issue you potentially have is that Turbolinks will also be an Ajax request. Ajax does not allow you to pass session variables correctly, which will likely mean that the flash notices will not make it through to your views.

Disabling Turbolinks, either with the above snippet, or by just removing it from your system for now, will give you a great line of testing to experiment with

Comment: I had tried putting

    = flash.notice

directly into the show.html.slim, and it did force notice to display. Also tried your suggestion, putting the -flash loop into show.html.slim, and that also did work.

Tried your suggestion re: turbolinks; "html: { data-no-turbolink: true}" causes a syntax error. But, when I disabled turbolink in application.html.slim like so:

    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => false
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => false

the notice still didn't show up.

Comment: Still don't understand why I would need to put code to display the flash notice directly into the view, though, as I don't need to do that for any other view to get flash notices to work properly.

Comment: Hmmm - did it work with your original code in your view?

Comment: I have like four other flash notices in other places, all of which display fine. This is the only one that seems to require putting = flash.notice directly into the view. The code in the application.html.slim takes care of all the other ones.

Comment: Hmmmmmm - do you have any issues with the other types of flash (error etc)?

Comment: How very strange - and your logs are the same as with the others?

Comment: Yes, and = debug flash output is exactly the same, regardless of if I have the view code in application.html slim or show.html.slim. Debug flash output shows that the notice is there in either case, but it only actually DISPLAYS if the view code is in show.html.slim.

Comment: Interestingly, if I create an assignment, and don't see the flash notice, and subsequently type in localhost:3000, the flash message will display *there*. (This is with view code only in application.html.slim.)

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, per se, but just some suggestions for debugging.

It sounds like the flash is getting set correctly in your controller, and is available on your page, but is maybe not hitting the layout file.

One possibility is that the layout isn't getting loaded at all on this page for some reason.

> You could test this by throwing a `raise` in the layout file, and seeing if it's hit when you load that page, or try to hit it in a spec.

If it is getting hit, one possibility is that there's some sort of CSS/display thing that is preventing the flash from displaying, even if it's there.

> You could test this by trying to inspect the page and find the flash HTML there, and see if you can alter the CSS to get it to display.

Another possibility, it sounds like, is that the flash is being set in the controller, but with weird timing.

> Maybe set a temporary before_action for that action that fills the flash every time the page is loaded with something else. Does that flash show on page load?

Hopefully one or all of those should help you isolate exactly what's going wrong, so that Googling or troubleshooting is more precise.

Answer (score 0):

In view page:

```
- flash.each do |message_type, message|
  %div{class: "alert #{flash_class(message_type)}"}
    = "message"
    %a.close{"aria-label" => "close", "data-dismiss" => "alert", href: "#", title: "close"} ×
= yield
```

In Helper:

```
  def flash_class flash_type
    case flash_type.to_sym
    when :success
      "alert-success"
    when :error, :alert, :danger
      "alert-danger"
    when :notice
      "alert-info"
    else
      "alert-warning"
    end
  end
```